# Connecting to a mysql database from a mysql-client pod

Tags: amazon-eks, kubernetes-statefulset

/ # mysql -u root -p -h pod/mysql-set-o.mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
Enter password:
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'pod/mysql-set-o.mysql.default.svc.cluster.local' (-2)

Hello, I just installed an eks statefulset cluster and has not been able to connect to the database. For spinning up the cluster, i used two services, a headless service and a secret service to manage my credentials. I am able to exec into the client pod so as to log into the data base. When i do that, it prompts for a password. when i enter the password as set in the secret, it throws the above error. Can someone help me? Im using eks 1.27 The yaml of my secret looks like this

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
name: mysql-password
type: opaque
stringData:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:password

Then the stateful set yaml looks like this
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mysql
labels:
app: mysql
spec:
ports:

- port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
  app: mysql

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
name: mysql-set
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app: mysql
serviceName: "mysql"
replicas: 2
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: mysql
spec:
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
containers:
- name: mysql
image: mysql:5.7
ports:
- containerPort: 3306
volumeMounts:
- name: mysql-store
mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
env:
- name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: mysql-password
key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
volumeClaimTemplates:

- metadata:
  name: mysql-store
  spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "manual"
  resources:
  requests:
  storage: 5Gi

Here is my client pod yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: mysql-client
spec:
containers:

- name: mysql-container
  image: alpine
  command: ['sh','-c', "sleep 1800m"]
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

i ran exec into my client pod and installed mysql client in it. It ran successfully. Then from the client pod i wanted to connect to my database server pod using

/ # mysql -u root -p -h pod/mysql-set-o.mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
It connected and asked me for a password. I was then expecting to put the password as: password and connect, but when i imputed the password, it gave me this error

Enter password:
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'pod/mysql-set-o.mysql.default.svc.cluster.local' (-2)